# Rancher static IP for containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos, rancher

I am trying to configure a few containers to use a static IP address added to the host.

I have the server configured with main IP `1.1.1.1` and added a virtual interface (eth0:0) with IP address `2.2.2.2` (`1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2` are just example IP addresses, to avoid leaving the real ones here).

I have been able to configure 2 containers to use that IP address, using hostports `2.2.2.2:8080` and `2.2.2.2:2222`.

I am now trying to add a third container, with hostport `2.2.2.2:80`

When I try to do that, I receive the following error:

`0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports.`

What configuration am I missing here? Rancher web interface is replying in `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2`, but I would like it to only use `1.1.1.1`, leaving the other IP addresses and ports for containers.

These are the commands I used to fire up rancher, and I am not sure if I should change the `80` or `443` part (on the left or the right) to match the correct public IP I want to map to rancher:

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 443:443 rancher/rancher
sudo docker run -d --privileged --restart=unless-stopped --net=host -v /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes -v /var/run:/var/run rancher/rancher-agent:v2.1.7 --server https://[MY_HOST] --token [token] --ca-checksum [ca-chaecksum] --etcd --controlplane --worker
```

Comment: Hi, you can check if the port is already occupied by other daemon or application on that node?  I beleibe  it could be first come and first serve

Comment: @SureshVishnoi please check the update I left in my post. Should I change that first command? How do I change the port mappings of an existing container? Can I do that through the rancher UI? Or how should I update that?

Comment: Don't use valid IP addresses that you don't own. 1.1.1.1 is a perfectly valid IP address (used by the Cloudflare DNS service), similarly 2.2.2.2 is also a valid IP address. It is unlikely you own the right to use either of those. Use the private address spaces (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 or 192.168.0.0/16)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry, it was not clear. 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 were just example IP addresses, I did not want to place the real ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info, I am deducing that you are using the same host to run Rancher and also register in a cluster.

When you specify `-p 80:80`, it means `0.0.0.0:80:80`, so all the IP addresses are used up. Hence when you try to run a container later to expose port 80, it will fail.

To be able to not listen on all IP addresses, you need to specify the IP address to listen on when running the Rancher server container.

Example: `docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 1.1.1.1:80:80 -p 1.1.1.1:443:443 rancher/rancher`

Comment: well, this sort of worked. I ran your command and it complained about the IP being bound. I stopped the container and ran the command afterwards. I am able to access rancher only in the desired IP address, but everything else is missing. No clusters, no workloads, nothing, even through I can see a lot of containers running in the command line. I have ran the 2 commands from my original question with the IP address, but no luck. any hints?

Comment: The command used to start Rancher doesn't have any volume specified, hence the information doesn't propagate from the old to the new one automatically. You need follow the upgrade steps to get that information out. Check out https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/upgrades/upgrades/single-node-upgrade/

Comment: Thank you. I have already created a question for this situation, can you please confirm if I should be executing the command I have in the update section of the post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55371611/rancher-configuration-lost