# Rancher configuration lost

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

I have restarted the rancher host a few times while configuring rancher.

Nothing was lost, even though containers had been started and stopped several times during these reboots.

I had to stop and run the container again to set a specific IP for the UI, so I could use the other IP addresses available in the host as HostPorts for containers.

This is the command I had to execute again:

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 1.2.3.4:80:80 -p 1.2.3.4:443:443 rancher/rancher
```

After running this, rancher started up as a clean installation, asking me for password, to setup a cluster, and do everything from scratch, even though I see a lot of containers running.

I tried rerunning the command that rancher showed on the first installation (including the old token and ca-checksum). Still nothing.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to restore the data, or should I do the configuration and container creation again?

What is the proper way of cleaning up, if I need to start from scratch? docker rm all containers and do the setup again?

**UPDATE**

I just found some information from another member in a related question, because this problem happened following a suggestion from another user.

Apparently there is an upgrade process that needs to be followed, but I am missing what needs to be done exactly. I can see my old, stopped container here: https://snag.gy/h2sSpH.jpg

I believe I need to do something with that container so the new rancher container becomes online with the previous data.

Should I be running this?

`docker run -d --volumes-from stoic_newton --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 443:443 rancher/rancher:latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I can confirm that this process works.

I have followed the guide here: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/upgrades/upgrades/single-node-upgrade/#completing-the-upgrade

I just add to stop the new rancher container which was lacking the data, copy if from the original docker container to create a backup, and then restart the new container with the volumes from the data container which was created in the process.

I could probably have launched the new rancher container with the volumes from the old rancher container, but I preferred playing it safe and following every step of the guide, and as a plus I ended up with a backup :)

Comment: I was just about to answer. But glad you figured it out.

Comment: thanks @leodotcloud your help was precious. I waited some hours for your answer and afterwards tried it on my own and left the answer here in case someone else stumbled upon this. all credits go to you :)